# How to pass li value to method in onclick event ? using react typescript

Tags: reactjs, react-tsx

```
<ul>
    <li id="1" onClick={this.currentvalue}>2</li>
    <li id="2" onClick={this.currentvalue}>3</li>
    <li id="3" onClick={this.currentvalue}>4</li>
    <li id="4" onClick={this.currentvalue}>5</li>
</ul>
```

In onClick event, I have given a currentValue handler

```
public currentvalue(e:React."WHICH EVENT I HAVE TO USE HERE"<WHICH HTML 
ELEMENT?>)
{
   global.console.log(e.target.value)
}
```

In the handler which event I have to use to get the target value?

Comment: getting `value` instead of `text` seems invalid to me. should be `event.target.innerText`

Answer (score 0):

Its s `React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>`.

```
public currentvalue(e: React.ClickEvent<HTMLInputElement>)
{
   global.console.log(e.target.value)
}
```

Comment: i am using onClick event. above code work for onChange event only @RIYAJ KHAN. but thanks for reply

Answer (score 0):

If you asking about type of event, you can use Event type:

```
public currentvalue(e: Event)
{
   global.console.log(e.target.value)
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event

Answer (score 0):

For accessing the value you need to include value attribute in the list elements as

```
<ul>
<li id="1" value="2"onClick={this.currentvalue}>2</li>
<li id="2" value ="3" onClick={this.currentvalue}>3</li>
<li id="3"  value ="4" onClick={this.currentvalue}>4</li>
<li id="4"  value ="5" onClick={this.currentvalue}>5</li>
</ul>
```

The currentvalue method can be as

```
public currentvalue(e:Event)
{
   global.console.log(e.target.value)
}
```

Comment: In typescript react, we have to specify which type element you are passing. please give me type of li element.

Comment: @chidambaraselvan You can use Event type,I have modified the code

Answer (score 0):

An elegant way may to bind the value to the function

wich result in something like this

```
public currentvalue(value:Integer, e:Event)
{
    global.console.log(value)
}
```

and in your component

```
<ul>
    <li id="1" onClick={this.currentvalue.bind(null, 2)}>2</li>
    <li id="2" onClick={this.currentvalue.bind(null, 3)}>3</li>
    <li id="3" onClick={this.currentvalue.bind(null, 4)}>4</li>
    <li id="4" onClick={this.currentvalue.bind(null, 5)}>5</li>
</ul>
```

to get it clear hear an working example https://codesandbox.io/s/6jl292nww

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
public currentvalue(e:React.MouseEvent<HTMLLIElement>)
{
   global.console.log(e.target.value)
}
```